# Faster convergence for minimizing least squares of forward modelling problems

Tags: optimization, numerical-modelling, convergence, least-squares

This specific question was raised from optimizing parameters of column experiments in the hydrogeological context. I want to optimize a parameter of interest (in this case $D$), based on experimental data (which is a **breakthrough curve**, an array of $c$ at the efflux-end of the column with corresponding $t$) and some forward modelling results.

The governing equation within the domain of interest (the column) is this advection-dispersion equation for solute transport (more source and sink terms like reaction/degradation/sorption are omitted for simplicity):
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D\frac{\partial^2 c}{\partial x^2} - u\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}$$

Forward modelling was performed with different values of $D$, and the corresponding outcome (as time series of $c$ at the last cell of the modelled domain (Neumann boundary condition at the efflux-end)) was compared with the experimental data. In the end the sum of squared residuals (SSR) between the numerical and the empirical data was calculated.

For optimizing $D$, my approach is:

1). set initial boundaries for $D$, use a couple of values within the ($D$) boundaries and perform the forward modelling respectively.

2). narrow the boundaries of $D$ by selecting those two with the 3rd and 2nd lowest SSR, and reiterate the step 1).

This approach works (like shown in the figures below), but I suppose not efficient enough. How can I reach the convergence of SSR faster in this forward modelling problem (I have no analytical solutions)? Thanks.

[image: SSR against D for case 1]
[image: SSR against D for case 2]

Comment: You're trying to find the minimum of a least squares function with an algorithm of your own design. What's wrong with using the algorithms everyone else is using and that have been developed over decades?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Of course there´s nothing wrong with the algorithms that are already available. The problem is that I don´t have a least squares function. You and I could see the trend of the SSRs because I enumerated enough of them by performing more than adequate amount of forward modelling computations. I wanted to ask how many points of SSRs should I know at least, or how should I enumerate new values of the parameter in question based on known SSRs, in order to reach the optimum value as fast as possible.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand then. What is it that you are trying to minimize, if not the SSR? Isn't the SSR a least squares functional?

Comment: The most basic minimization algorithm works similar to the false-position method. Each step starts with 3 points with the value in the middle the minimizer of the three. Then take the minimum of the parabola through these points and their values as next point and restore the original situation, typically removing the largest value. Similar stalling prevention principles should apply (reducing the value at the stalled point).

Comment: Is D a function of space only? What is your numerical scheme to compute the derivatives? Did you try a simple gradient descent?